# Why are there limitations on using encryption with keys beyond certain length?

Tags: encryption

I am writing a java program to encrypt a message using 256-bit AES encryption, but I am getting `illegal key size error`, I have read that I have to use some JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files to encrypt/decrypt message with key of 256-bit or longer, but I do not understand why there is a limit on using a key size? Why using 256-bit encryption is disabled in Java by default?

Is it a crime to encrypt/decrypt files using 256-bit keys?

Comment: Actually Oracle Java requires the Unlimited Policy addon to do symmetric crypto _more than 128 bits_; that includes AES-192 and AES-256. It is impossible to use more than 256 bits key in _any_ AES implementation, Java or other, because AES doesn't do that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many different cryptography laws in different nations. Some countries prohibit export of cryptography software and/or encryption algorithms or cryptoanalysis methods.

In some countries a license is required to use encryption software, and a few countries ban citizens from encrypting their internet communication. Some countries require decryption keys to be recoverable in case of a police investigation.

Issues regarding cryptography law fall into four categories:

- **Export control**, which is the restriction on export of cryptography methods within a country to other countries
  or commercial entities. There are international export control agreements, the main one being the [Wassenaar Arrangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassenaar_Arrangement). The Wassenaar Arrangement was created after the dissolution of [COCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOM) (Coordinating committee for Multilateral Export Controls), which in 1989 "decontrolled password and authentication-only cryptography."
- **Import controls, which is the restriction on using certain types of**
  **cryptography within a country.**
- **[Patent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent) issues**, which deal with the use of cryptography tools that are
  patented.
- **[Search and seizure issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_and_seizure)s**, on whether and under what circumstances, a
  person can be compelled to decrypt data files or reveal an encryption
  key.

**Restrictions on the import of cryptography**

Countries may wish to restrict import of cryptography technologies for a number of reasons:

- Cryptography may increase levels of privacy within the country beyond
  what the government wishes.
- Citizens can anonymously communicate with each other, preventing any
  external party from monitoring them.
- Encrypted transactions may impede external entities to control the
  conducting of business.
- Imported cryptography may have backdoors or security holes,
  intentional or not, which allow foreigners to spy on persons using
  the imported cryptography; therefore the use of cryptography is
  restricted to that which the government thinks is safe, or which it
  develops itself.

The [Electronic Privacy Information Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Privacy_Information_Center) and Global Internet Liberty Campaign reports use a color code to indicate the level of restriction, with the following meanings:

- **Green**: No restriction
- **Yellow**: License required for importation
- **Red**: Total ban

Here is [List of Countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_the_import_of_cryptography#Status_by_country), each with their level of import restrictions.

[image]

and [**List of Countries with their import/export restrictions details and explanation**](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#busigov)

### Import Limits on Cryptographic Algorithms in Java

Due to import regulations in some countries, the Oracle implementation provides a default cryptographic jurisdiction policy file that limits the strength of cryptographic algorithms.

If stronger algorithms are needed (for example, AES with 256-bit keys), the [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html) must be obtained and installed in the JDK/JRE.

It is the user's responsibility to verify that this action is permissible under local regulations.

Comment: Note that since 8u161 circa Jan 2018 the default is now unlimited "Enable unlimited cryptographic policy by default in Oracle JDK builds", https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170157.