# Can you travel out of the U.S. with Oracle's JCE Unlimited Strength installed on your laptop?

Tags: encryption, key-size

Just curious if this "export" restriction applies to general travel outside the U.S. with [**Oracle's JCE Unlimited Strength**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html) installed on a laptop.

pertinent text from Oracle's "[Java SE BCL License Agreement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html)"

> 7. EXPORT REGULATIONS. You agree that U.S. export control laws and other applicable export and import laws govern your use of the Software, including technical data; additional information can be found on Oracle's Global Trade Compliance web site (www.oracle.com/us/products/export). You agree that neither the Software nor any direct product thereof will be exported, directly, or indirectly, in violation of these laws, or will be used for any purpose prohibited by these laws including, without limitation, nuclear, chemical, or biological weapons proliferation.

This crypto Q&A discusses the issue in general: 
[Why there are limitations on using encryption with keys beyond certain length?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20524/why-there-are-limitations-on-using-encryption-with-keys-beyond-certain-length/20525#20525?newreg=d2b006d1830c4184bb672cfd87894270)

Comment: This probably belongs on lawyers SE, not here. We deal with cryptographic algorithms, not law.

Comment: Probably true, didn't know how broad **crypto** topics are.  Anyone else have an opinion?

Comment: Related discussion on Meta about legal questions on crypto.SE between two mods [here](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/206/are-legal-issues-surrounding-cryptography-on-topic-here). Spoiler: deemed off topic (which makes the linked Q/A probably also off topic, by the way, but that's for the mods to ponder over I assume).

Comment: Right. Good eye on that convo.  I think I may agree with @mikeazo recommending [law.se] with [tag:cryptography] tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because the question is about law, not cryptography.

Comment: Is there an easy way to move this to [law.se]?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention and write that you propose this question to be migrated to law SE.